# How to call a custom method after Mapreduce Job completition using Hadoop java api?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run a mapreduce program, just WordCount for my better understanding. Everything is working pretty fine like it suppose. I want to call a function after the completion of a MapReduce program and in that function I want to merge all the part-files made in the reduce step to a single textfile containing the contents of all the part-files. I have seen related problem and people suggested to use **FileUtil.copyMerge** function. My question is how to make function call such that it gets executed after whole mapreduce process.

```
public class mapreducetask  {

private void filesmerger(){
    // I want to merge partfiles here in the function(maybe using FileUtils.copyMerge)
}

public static void main(String [] args) throws  Exception{
    Configuration cnf = new Configuration();
    cnf.set("mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.seperator",":");

    Integer numberOfReducers = 3;
    Job jb = new Job(cnf,"mapreducejob");
    jb.setJarByClass(mapreducetask.class);
    jb.setMapperClass(mapper.class);
    jb.setNumReduceTasks(numberOfReducers);
    jb.setReducerClass(reducer.class);
    jb.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    jb.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    jb.setInputFormatClass(customfileinputformat.class);

    Path input = new Path("Input");
    Path output = new Path ("Output");
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(jb, input);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jb, output);

    // Should I call my merger function here. Location 1
    System.exit(jb.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);
  }

}
```

When I'm making a call from Location 1(see the code) it seems to get executed even before mapreduce program which I don't want. How can I call function after completion of a Mapreduce process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the code in Location 1 before you call `jb.waitForCompletion(true)`. You need to call it after (and obviously not call `System.exit()`). So:

```
jb.waitForCompletion(true);
//Run your code
```

Comment: Cool. This works just file. Can you tell me if there exist a better way to achieve the same ? Or is this okay.